# Can't execute PDO query (Invalid parameter number) but it is not invalid

Tags: php, mysql, parameters, pdo, warnings

I have in the same class three functions and functions consists db queries.
In other functions are the queries ok, like in this:

```
$userId = $_SESSION['uid'];

        $st = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM showinfo, usershows WHERE usershows.showid = showinfo.showid AND usershows.userid = :userId");
        $st->bindParam('userId', $userId);
        $st-> execute();
```

But here the query doesn't work:

```
$st = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM usershows WHERE usershows.userid = :userId");
            $st->bindParam(':userid', $userId);
            $st->execute();
```

It says:

Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in (file location)

And the code can echo out my userId, so this can not be empty.

Any suggestions?

Comment: In the SQL, it's called `:userId`; in bindParam, it's called `:userid` - I suspect they should be the same case.

Answer (score 2):

In your second examples `bindParam()` you need to use `:userId` and not `:userid`

PHP is case sensitive!

Comment: PHP is _mostly_ case sensitive. Function names aren't. Yay for consistency.